# How to read and decode a file outside of my application folder?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-bitmap, android-file

I am trying to use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` method in my gallery image but it was returning null then I found the images outside of my app folder is not readable, but the same code was decoding the file in a marshmallow device, now it is not working on android pi. 
Here is my code snippet:

```
fun compressImage(file: File, fileSizeInKB: Int, context: Context): File {
        val outputBounds = 800
        val scaleOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
        scaleOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.path, scaleOptions)

        val scaleFactor =   if(scaleOptions.outHeight > outputBounds || scaleOptions.outWidth > outputBounds)
                                        kotlin.math.max(scaleOptions.outWidth/outputBounds.toFloat(), scaleOptions.outHeight/outputBounds.toFloat())
                                    else 1F

        val outOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
        outOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor.roundToInt()
        outOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565
        outOptions.inDither = true
        val decodedBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.path, outOptions)
        // Do something with the bitmap
}
```

I am not getting the bounds of the image after first decode and also in the next decode function `decodedBMP` is null. I have given runtime permissions already and I tried `file.setReadable(true, false)` but still `file` is not readable.

Comment: How exactly are you getting the value for `file`?

Comment: I am sending file parameter as File(uri.path), in case of files within my app folder it was working fine, do I need to change that?

Comment: "I am sending file parameter as File(uri.path)" -- a `Uri` is not a file. Use `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` associated with the `Uri`. Then, pass that to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`. Or, use an image-loading library like Glide or Picasso.

Comment: Thank you it's working now 